# Intellij - Git error : The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 12.1.4 to interact with Git. My Windows password recently changed and thenceforth, I could not push to any of my Git Repos. I kept getting

> The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401

I suspect its an authentication issue but I don't know which files in the Intellij cache keep the old password information, so that i can delete those and get running again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, if you had selected "Remember Passwords" in the Intellij screen when you pushed for the first time, Intellij will keep using the old password it stored and not prompt you for the new one.

To fix this, go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Passwords</kbd> and select "Remember Passwords until the Application is Closed". Once you restart Intellij, it will wipe out the older authentication information and it will prompt you, once again, for your new shiny password with which you can push to Git.